# Saving output of a program in text file

Tags: powershell, edit

I'm trying to store the output of a program into a text file using PowerShell, but it doesn't quite work.

It executes the program, and creates the text file, but it comes out empty.

```
./program /stext file.txt
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pipe the result to the `Out-File` cmdlet:

```
./program | Out-File file.txt
```

Comment: Nevermind, you're technically correct, but I just realized I did not get the command-line version of the program.